# Puppet-Apt fails to install package because of verification

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtual-machine, puppet, apt

**Environment:**

Running CentOs 7.2 Server in a virtual machine, which has a local proxy set up with CNTLM. I have installed vagrant version 1.8.1. In addition i installed the vagrant-proxyconf plugin.

**Goal:**

Set up a virtual machine on the CentOs 7.2 Server with vagrant.

Yes: A virtual machine in a virtual machine.

**Status quo:**

A snippet of the Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.proxy.http = http://10.0.2.2:3128
config.proxy.https = http://10.0.2.2:3128
config.proxy.no_proxy = localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.0.2.*
...

# puppet config
config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "../puppet/modules" do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "../puppet/manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "base.pp"
  # In facts are the proxy settings with host and port. 
  puppet.facter = facts
end
```

A snippet of my puppet manifest:

```
class box-configuration {
  ...
  class { 'apt':
   always_apt_update => true;
  } 

  # Always a apt-key update before installing packages 
  exec { 'apt-key_update':
   command => "/usr/bin/apt-key update && /usr/bin/apt-get update",
   require => Class['apt'],
  }
  apt::ppa { 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa': }

  package { ["unzip", "curl", "openjdk-8-jdk"]:
    ensure => present,
    require => [Class['apt'], Exec['apt-key_update']],
  }
...
}
```

**Problem:**

When i'm running `vagrant up` in the terminal, i get the following error for the package `openjdk-8-jdk`:
[image]

All other packages could be installed successfully.

After the failure, i connected to the virtual machine with `vagrant ssh` to install this package manually with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` and then i got the following prompt:

```
 Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

`apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` wants a verification for downloading the package from the recently added repository in `base.pp`.

What should i do for this? I already add the `Exec['apt-key_update']` requirement...

**EDIT:**
When i connect to the virtual machine with `vagrant ssh` to make manually the update `apt-key update && apt-get update` i get the following output:

[image: apt-key update]
[image: apt-get update]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net)  with the version 0.92.3.. They have some problems in this version with the proxy tunneling. They recommend to install the 0.93beta5 version, and this solved my problem... But you can't get the beta version from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/).. I download the beta version from this [repository](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Amichalstrnad&package=cntlm).

Otherwise check the answer of @Frédéric Henri, this could solve your problem, when everything with CNTLM is ok.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have dependencies on the `apt::ppa { 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa': }` when you install the java package, so you can make a dep

```
apt::ppa { 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa': }
exec { 'apt-key_update':
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-key update && /usr/bin/apt-get update",
  require => [Class['apt'], Apt::ppa['ppa:openjdk-r/ppa']],
}
package { ["unzip", "curl", "openjdk-8-jdk"]:
  ensure => present,
  require => [Class['apt'], Exec['apt-key_update']],
}
```

EDIT : I tested on ubuntu/trusty64 box and I used the [apt module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt) (you need to make sure it is installed) and the following puppet file

```
class box-configuration {

  class { 'apt':
    update => {
      frequency => 'always',
    },
  } 

  # Always a apt-key update before installing packages 
  exec { 'apt-key_update':
   command => "/usr/bin/apt-key update && /usr/bin/apt-get update",
   require => [Class['apt'], Apt::Ppa['ppa:openjdk-r/ppa']]
  }
  apt::ppa { 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa': }

  package { ["unzip", "curl", "openjdk-8-jdk"]:
    ensure => present,
    require => [Class['apt'], Exec['apt-key_update']],
  }
}

include box-configuration
```

everything goes fine and java8 is installed - you can see a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fhenri/33c4a6796f461a3acd82f30506b5d5f3) of all the installation process

Comment: Why i get the following error: `` Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '::ppa'; expected ']' `?

Comment: Ok i found the mistake, it's `Apt::Ppa` and not `Apt::ppa`

Comment: Unfortunately i still get the same error, do you have any suggestions? You can add it, in your answer, please :(.

Comment: really weird indeed ... I am able to make it work .. are you able to share the rest of the project (in github or something) so I can see your Vagrantfile, other script and try to replay .. there's no reason it should not work

Comment: I was able to make it work on my own MacOS, where is no corporate proxy with authentication... But on my workstation @work is a proxy. Do you think there is a problem to run it behind a local proxy with CNTLM, which encapsulates the corporate proxy with authentication?

Comment: Have a look in my question, i added some more information.

Comment: run the following `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXX` and replace XXX with the 2 keys you have in the message, it should pass the question - if ok you can add in your puppet file

Comment: How can I add this in puppet? Are these keys unique for me or can I share this puppet file in a repository with others ??

Comment: The Problem was not the manifest file either any configuration in vagrant or puppet. The problem occured because of CNTLM v.0.92.3! This version has proxy problems and they recommend to use the v.0.93beta5 version. Or you set env variable http_proxy and https_proxy with authentication like this: `export http_proxy="http://user:pass@server:port"`

Comment: Good, anyway the first pbm was indeed on `require Apt::Ppa['ppa:openjdk-r/ppa']`